# How I can get layout from Float Action Button android

Tags: java, android

I want get layout from Float Action Button. I did this with Snackbar like

```
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
```

Can I get a layout similar to the above method?
I want get layout FROM FAB.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FloatingActionButton extends ImageButton, which extends ImageView. So there isn't any layout to get from it. It's an ImageView so what you could eventually get is a Drawable. If you want to customise it, you'll need to play with its drawable.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I can't tell you how to do it if I don't know what you want to do. I suggest you to read the [drawable docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)